# Pycharm autocomplete does not work for TypeVar with bounds

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, type-hinting

When I use TypeVar with bounds in Pycharm, there are no hints related to the upper bound of the Typevar. Example:

```
from typing import TypeVar

class TestClass:

    def test_class_method(self):
        print("test")

T = TypeVar('T', bound=TestClass)

def test_method(test_class: T):
    test_class.test_class_method()

test_method(TestClass())
```

Here, I would expect the `test_class method` to be listed in autocomplete when I hit ctrl + space on `test_class`. But there is nothing. When I highlight the `test_class`, there is a tooltip saying correctly: *Inferred type: TypeVar('T', TestClass)*. Is there a mistake on my side, or is it a autocomplete issue?

Comment: Please file an issue in [the bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)

Comment: Observed the same issue with PyCharm. Did you end up filing a bug?

Comment: @KFL yes, it is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25832